# How to make a parameter optional in WSDL?

Tags: wsdl, parameters, option-type

I have a WebService API which needs 2 of its parameters to be optional in the WSDL

```
public wsProxy[] Insert(wsProxy[] proxies, string loginname, string password, bool returnNewData)
{
  //code here
}
```

I need to a way to show `loginname` and `password` as optional in the WSDL.

Is there any way to do this in C#.  Can I maybe add an tag in front of the parameters like this `[optional]loginname`?

I have been looking around but haven't been able to find anything so far.

Answer (score 0):

They will, by default, appear as optional in the WSDL generated by WCF (let me know if you know of a way to disable this horrid behavior).